# How to set a value by key for a dictionary in python using the map function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I know that I can set a key-value pair by using

`dict[key] = value`

but I have a very long list of dicts of the type

```
dict = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4},
        {a:2, b:3, c:4, d:5},
        {a:5, b:7, c:3, d:9}]
```

and I'd like to do something along the lines of

`dict = map(lambda x: x['d'] <- x['d'] -1, dict)`

how would I go about this? (This is a very simplified example so I'm not really trying to just subtract a number from all items by a particular key)

expected output would be in **this** case and **not** the *general case* I'm looking for

```
[{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:3},
 {a:2, b:3, c:4, d:4},
 {a:5, b:7, c:3, d:8}]
```

**EDIT: 2**

I believe the following does not work - so any similar solution would be helpful:

`dict = map(lambda x: x.update(d, x[d] - 1), dict)`

Comment: can you also update the expected output

Comment: `dict` is a very poor name for an object that is actually a list!

Comment: Hi @Borodin - the name is just to reinforce that it is a list of dicts on SO and I agree a bad choice.. In the actual code the list is called 'price_feed'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this: as exactly you said

```
>>> dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4},
         {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5},
         {'a':5, 'b':7, 'c':3, 'd':9}]
>>> map(lambda x:x.update([('d',x['d']-1)]),dicts)
[None, None, None]
>>> dicts
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 3}, {'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'b': 7, 'd': 8}]
```

`update` will update the dictionary with (key,value) pair. Returns None

Answer (score 3):

```
dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4},
         {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5},
         {'a':5, 'b':7, 'c':3, 'd':9}]

for d in dicts:
    d['d'] -= 1
```

Output:

```
In [94]: dicts
Out[94]: 
[{'d': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1},
 {'d': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'a': 2},
 {'d': 8, 'b': 7, 'c': 3, 'a': 5}]
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` is a way of transforming an iterable to a list by performing the same operation on every item from the iterable. I don't think that's what you want to do here, and it has confused you.

On the face of it (although you haven't mentioned what the *real* operation is that you want to perform) a simple `for` is all that is necessary:

```
dict_list = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5},
    {'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 3, 'd': 9},
]

for d in dict_list:
    d['d'] -= 1
    print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 3}
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 4}
{'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 3, 'd': 8}
```

Comment: hi @Borodin I have a number of different things I'm trying to do with the function: some use-case examples are change the date to datetime format, change numbers to float (data scrubbing) and convert a list of prices to a single currency. Thanks

Comment: @TahnoonPasha: Okay. That should still be fine using `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict.__setitem__` and temporary list (or any other collection typer) trick:

```
>>> dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4},
...          {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5},
...          {'a':5, 'b':7, 'c':3, 'd':9}]
>>> map(lambda d: [d.__setitem__('d', d['d'] - 1), d][1], dicts)
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 3},
 {'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 3, 'd': 4},
 {'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'b': 7, 'd': 8}]
```

Using simple `for` loop is moe recommended way. Especially there's a side effect in the function.

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name. It will shadows builtin function/type [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
my_dict = {k: f(v) for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

where f is whatever function you want.